# It's sophisticated because I mentioned Silmarillion

Tags: wordplay, geography, cryptic-clues

> 1. Dwarf fellow with ring next to container leads to volcano (11)
> 2. Hamlet follows holy unity to rocky settlement (5 4)
> 3. Sacred five-peaker to hop onto Silmarillion creator after first of month (5 4)
> 4. Acquire insect's head following endlessly peaceful national park (9)
> 5. Extinct avian parent capital (6)

Where are we?

Comment: for 1: related to r13(ybeq bs gur evatf)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are in

> Tanzania

1. Dwarf fellow with ring next to container leads to volcano (11)

   > Kilimanjaro = [Kili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth_dwarf_characters#K%C3%ADli) + man + jar + o
2. Hamlet follows holy unity to rocky settlement (5 4)

   > Stone Town = St. + one + Town
3. Sacred five-peaker to hop onto Silmarillion creator after first of month (5 4)

   > Mount Meru = Mount + M(onth) + [Eru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eru_Il%C3%BAvatar)
4. Acquire insect's head following endlessly peaceful national park (9)

   > Serengeti = Seren(e) + get + i(nsect)
5. Extinct avian parent capital (6)

   > Dodoma = Dodo + ma